# Задача на расстановку гирь в сумму простых чисел

Tags: математика, рекурсия, олимпиада

Условие [задачи](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=448):

> Имеются гири с массами: 1 г, 2 г, …, N г .Требуется написать
> программу, распределяющую эти гири на максимально возможное количество
> пар так, чтобы суммарный вес гирь в каждой паре выражался простым
> числом.
>
> **Входные данные** Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит единственное
> натуральное число N, не превосходящее 500 000.
>
> **Выходные данные** В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите список найденных
> пар. Каждая пара выводится в одной строке через пробел.

Сразу говорю, меня больше интересует идея и доказательство решения, а не код. (вопрос получается скорее математический)

Первое, что навевает на ум - найти наименьшее простое число большее `n`, к которому мы будем приравнивать наши суммы и выводить. Такое простое число обязательно найдется по [постулату Бертрана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0), т.к. наш диапазон сумм лежит в диапазоне `[n + 1; 2n - 1] <=> (n;2n)`

1. А может искать простое надо не большее чем `n`? Искомый диапазон сумм же `[3; 2n - 1]`. Распространение простых чисел неопределенно и поэтому может возникнуть плохая ситуация.. То есть допустим, у меня есть `n`, а следующее ближайшее простое `n + 4000`. И представим, что `n - 2` - простое (если вопрос почему не `n - 1`, то `n + 4000` - простое => `n + 4000` - нечетное => `n` - нечетное, `n - 1` - четно и имеет делитель `2`, `n - 2` не имеет подобного делителя). Очевидно, что мне нужно выбрать `n - 2` и, благодаря этому выбору, я получу максимальное количество сумм. Или же такая ситуация невозможна? И почему?
2. Вопрос с количеством ответов. На одном из [форумов](http://rsdn.org/forum/alg/75191.all) прочитал что количество ответов - `n/2` (целочисленной деление), и с этим утверждением я не сильно согласен, но и доказать не сильно смогу. Допустим я дано `n` и `p > n`. Тогда мои решения: (`p - n` + `n`); (`p - n + 1` + `n - 1`); (`p - n + 2` + `n - 3`) ... и т.д. пока они станут равными или одно слагаемое станет больше другого. Тут получается гарантированно `(n - (p - n))/2 <=> (2n - p)/2 <=> n - (p - 1)/2` пар (почленное деление и p - простое, априрори нечетное, значит уменьшаем на 1 чтобы получилось целочисленное деление). Но у нас же остались еще числа `1, 2, 3, 4 ... p - n - 1`. Получается исходная задача. Тут есть (p - n)/2 пар То есть, мы доказали для какого то большого случая, что разложение в пары есть. Теперь для меньшего очевидно тоже есть (мат. индукция). Только вот вопрос как добраться до ответа `n/2`. Если представить, что все оставшиеся числа можно представить в виде суммы простых чисел, то все становится тривиально - `1, 2, 3, 4 ... p - n - 1` имеет `(p - n)/2` количество пар. Суммируем с исходными парами `(2n - p)/2 + (p - n)/2 <=> (2n - p + p - n)/2 <=> n/2`. Однако может быть, что не все числа можно собирать в сумму одного и тоже простое числа. Но мы же доказали для большого случая, что мы можем создавать пары? а значит и этот можем создавать нужные пары. И так бесконечно. Но максимальное количество пар - и есть n/2, значит это по идее и должно являться ответом. Я делаю допущение, что лучший выбор - выбор ближайшего простого после `n`. Так что доказательство не полное без первого пункта.

в случае непоняток пишите, я дополню и сделаю некоторые вещи поподробнее

сам алгоритм: ([acmp](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=448) зачел как верное, что в какой то степени подтверждает верность 1 пункта, но как доказать его все еще не знаю)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool check_prime(int n) //проверка простоты
{
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

int next_prime(int n) //следующее простое число большее n
{
    int next_prime = n + 1 + (n & 1);
    while (!check_prime(next_prime))
        next_prime += 2;
    return next_prime;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    while (n > 1) //пока существуют пары
    {
        int prime = next_prime(n);
        int l; //левая граница
        for (size_t i = 1;; i++)
        {
            if (i + n == prime) //находим границу
            {
                l = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        int cnt = 0;
        for (size_t i = l; i <= (n + l)/2; i++)
        {
            cout << i << " " << n - cnt++ << endl; //выводим пары
        }
        n = l - 1; //решаем случай для чисел 1,2,3 ... l - 1 и решаем до тех пор пока не останется 1 число
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрел, по-моему, все верно. Вполне приемлемое рекурсивное решение.

Что до `N/2` пар. Давайте подойдем к этому чуть-чуть иначе. Главное - что на очередном шагу рекурсии:

- вы всегда при N>1 можете получить *какое-то* **ненулевое** количество пар решений, т.е. оставшееся количество чисел строго меньше исходного.
- эти числа также имеют вид последовательности 1 2 3 4 ...

Это дает нам:

Рекурсия завершится, и тогда у вас будет либо 0, либо 1 число в последовательности. На каждом шагу образуются **только пары**, и эти числа из последовательности убираются. Но если у вас остается только 0(1) число из `N`, а *все остальные - в парах*, то сколько всего пар получается? N/2 для четного, (N-1)/2 для нечетного, или  целочисленно деленное N/2.

Вот и все.

Я вас убедил? :)

Comment: очень даже убедили) по сути второй пункт говорит, что любую последовательность можно разложить в "нужные" пары и так делать бесконечно. но очевидно бесконечно делать нельзя, у нас же всего `n/2` пар. значит это и будет конечной точкой.